# Problems with Arduino remotely controlling an outlet

Tags: c, arduino

This is a project that will be turned in, in 8 hours! We are stuck with this problem and thought of this place as a kind of last resort.

I'm trying to turn on/off a remotely controlled outlet with an Arduino.
We get inconsistencies when doing so. Sometimes when it goes into the `if` statement that `”should be ON”` but instead turns the power off of the outlet and vice versa.

**Code:**

```
// on off remote control
int off = 12;
int on = 13;

void setup() {

  pinMode(off, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin as output
  pinMode(on, OUTPUT);

}
void loop() {

  // ..first we getting response from server if remote control should be on/off,
  // working fine so not really relevant to problem.

  // then we determine if outlet should be ON or OFF:
  response.toCharArray(responseCharArray,100);
    if(strstr( responseCharArray, "active") && strstr( responseCharArray, "1")) {
      // This should turn ON the outlet.
      digitalWrite(on, HIGH); 
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(on, LOW);
      Serial.println("should be ON");
    }
    else if(strstr( responseCharArray, "active") && strstr( responseCharArray, "0")) {
      // This should turn OFF the outlet.
      digitalWrite(off, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(off, LOW);
      Serial.println("should be OFF");
    }

}
```

**Picture of the wiring:**
[image]

**Question:**
What could be missing here? Since it randomly turns it on/off while entering same if statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is too little information here.

Notice that your code will trigger (turn on) if `responseCharArray` contains something like e.g. `"retroactively from 1941"`, or turn off for something like `"active for 37 seconds"`.

In other words, that string-matching is not very precise, but it's hard to know what it should be since I don't know anything about the format of the response.

Perhaps it should at least be

```
if(strstr(responseCharArray, "active=1") != NULL)
```

or something, to at least lock the `1` to the `active` part.

In the logging that you do, print out the value of `responseCharArray` too. This will let you analyze whether or no the decision-making made sense.

Also, as always, triple-check your wiring and watch for e.g. back-feeding.

Comment: I'm aware that the check in our if-case is somewhat not-precise, but it works for us. I think our problem is hardware related. but thanks for your input anyway! cheers.